# Adobe Acrobat Reader's scanner produces blue image

Tags: adobe-reader, document-scanner

I just scanned an white sheet of paper with the scanner in the Adobe Acrobat Reader app and I got a blue hued image. I tried changing the scanned image to original and I still got a blue image.

I tried scanning the same document with CamScanner and there was no problem there. I recieved a normal image with no blue tint.

What should I do?

Comment: My phone is Samsung Galaxy J5 2015 model running Android 5.1.1

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is?  Apps can work differently.  Do you need to use Acrobat Reader for scanning?  Does CamScanner not output to the right format?  Etc.